# issue with adding two-dimensional array to string python

Tags: python, arrays

please help me.
I have two-dimensional array example :

```
self.history = [['23295', u'0.0500',  u'0.0700', u'0.0600', u'0.0600'],['23295', u'0.0500', u'0.0700', u'0.0600', u'0.0600']]
```

i try parsing him and get string but have syntax error, please advice.

```
for i in  range(int(cac)):
    returning = returning + "\""+str(date_arr[i])+","+ str(self.history[0 for x in range(len(self.history))][i])+"+"
```

in output i need have somethings like :

```
"somedate,'23295','23295'" + "somedate,u'0.0500',u'0.0500'" + "somedate,u'0.0700',u'0.0700'"...
```

Comment: the problem is here: `[0 for x in range(len(self.history))]`

Comment: i have in output somethings like that :
"2014-11-13 18:44,[0]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use two `for` loops:

```
for x in range(len(self.history)):
    for i in  range(int(cac)):
        returning = returning + "\""+str(date_arr[i])+","+ str(self.history[x][i])+"+"
```

Note that your code `[x for x in range(len(self.history))]` [generates a list](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) whereas you need an integer to index your list

Comment: thanks, but as result i have : "2014-11-13 18:45,[0]"2014-11-13 18:46,[0]"2014-11-13 18:47,[0]"2014-11-13 18:48,[0]"2014-11-13 18:49,[0]"2014-11-13 18:50,[0]"2014-11-13 18:51,[0]"2014-11-13 18:52,[0]"...

Comment: thanks really for the help, but there is back (example): self.history[0][0], self.history[1][0], self.history[0][1], self.history[1][1], but need in this order :
self.history[0][0], self.history[0][1], self.history[0][1], self.history[1][1]...
I hope you understand and again thanks

Comment: @user3731374 simply change the position of `for` loops as I edited my answer